# What does Verax mean in the context of Firebase Security Rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I noticed the Firebase docs mention "Verax ruleset" when listing Firestore Security Rules limits. It's never mentioned anywhere else.

Is this an internal naming of their implementation that shouldn't have made it to the public docs?

Source:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-behavior

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Verax is an internal code name for the engine that evaluates the security rules of Firestore and Storage.

This should not be mentioned by name in the documentation though, so we've updated the documentation remove it.